# Set Orientation to Picture with AVFoundation in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, orientation

I'm new to Swift and I don't have a lot programming exercise so maybe this problem is simple to solve for you O:-)...

I only need a simple Camera with AVFoundation to capture pictures, no live mode or video recording is needed.
I have a problem with the video orientation and wasn't able to find the answer in the forum by now. I know that many people have this problem, but all I tried did not work and I am not able to solve this problem in my code. I don't really understand how capturing pictures with AVFoundation works and where exactly the picture is taken...

Can you tell me how to set the device image orientation to the picture so that it will be shown with the device orientation when I use the picture in an image view?

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var imageProcessedView: UIImageView!
var imageProcessed: UIImage?
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()

    imageProcessedView.alpha = 1.0
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
    backCamera()
}

func backCamera()
{
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

    for device in devices! {
        if ((device as AnyObject).hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)){
            captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
            do {
                try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
            break
        }
    }
 }


//Session starts and preview appears:
@IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    if captureDevice != nil
    {
        imageProcessedView.alpha = 0.0
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
        previewLayer?.frame = self.cameraView.layer.bounds
        previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        captureSession.startRunning()
        stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput){
            captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
        }
        }else{
            print("No captureDevice")
        }

}

@IBAction func capturePicture(_ sender: Any) {
    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo){

        var currentDevice: UIDevice
        currentDevice = .current

        var deviceOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation
        deviceOrientation = currentDevice.orientation

        //variables to set the orientation as parameter like "portrait" and as rawValue like the integer 0 for portrait mode
        var avCaptureOrientation: AVCaptureVideoOrientation
        avCaptureOrientation = .portrait

        var orientationValue: Int
        orientationValue = 0

        if deviceOrientation == .portrait {
            avCaptureOrientation = .portrait
            orientationValue = 0
            print("Device: Portrait")
        }else if (deviceOrientation == .landscapeLeft){
            avCaptureOrientation = .landscapeLeft
            orientationValue = 3
            print("Device: LandscapeLeft")
        }else if (deviceOrientation == .landscapeRight){
            avCaptureOrientation = .landscapeRight
            orientationValue = 2
            print("Device LandscapeRight")
        }else if (deviceOrientation == .portraitUpsideDown){
            avCaptureOrientation = .portraitUpsideDown
            orientationValue = 1
            print("Device PortraitUpsideDown")
        }else{
            print("Unknown Device Orientation")
        }

        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {(imageDataSampleBuffer, error) in
        let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)

            let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
            self.imageProcessed = image!
            //In this print command always "3" appears
            print("Metadata Orientation: \(image!.imageOrientation.rawValue)")
            //in this view the orientation is correct but later when I use the picture to display it in an imageView it is wrong
            self.cameraView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image!)

            self.captureSession.stopRunning()
        })
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Marina

---

Ok now I changed my code a little. I can see the correct DeviceOrientation and also the imageOrientation seems to be correct, as it is shown in the print command.

But I still have the problem, that putting the picture is orientated wrong when I put it into the imageView (it is also scaled a way too big).

The function where I want to set the picture into the image view is:

```
@IBAction func showCirclesInPic(_ sender: Any) {
    if imageProcessed != nil {
        previewLayer!.removeFromSuperlayer()
        cameraView.addSubview(imageProcessedView)

        if (imageProcessed!.imageOrientation != .up){
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageProcessed!.size, false, imageProcessed!.scale)
            imageProcessed!.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: imageProcessed!.size.width, height: imageProcessed!.size.height))
            imageProcessed = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
        imageProcessedView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageProcessedView.image = imageProcessed
        //print("ImageProcessed: \(ImageProcessingCV.showCircles(imageProcessed)!)")
    }
}
```

**Here is the rest of my changed Code:**

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var imageProcessedView: UIImageView!
var imageProcessed: UIImage?
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageProcessedView.alpha = 1.0
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
    backCamera()
}



func backCamera()
{
    let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()

    for device in devices! {
        if ((device as AnyObject).hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)){
            captureDevice = device as? AVCaptureDevice
            do {
                try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
            } catch {
                print("error")
            }
            break
        }
    }
 }



@IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
    if captureDevice != nil
    {
        imageProcessedView.alpha = 0.0
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
        previewLayer?.frame = self.cameraView.layer.bounds
        previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        captureSession.startRunning()
        stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput){
            captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
        }
        }else{
            print("No captureDevice")
        }

}

@IBAction func capturePicture(_ sender: Any) {
    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo){

        var currentDevice: UIDevice
        currentDevice = .current
        UIDevice.current.beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
        var deviceOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation
        deviceOrientation = currentDevice.orientation

        var imageOrientation: UIImageOrientation?

        if deviceOrientation == .portrait {
            imageOrientation = .up
            print("Device: Portrait")
        }else if (deviceOrientation == .landscapeLeft){
            imageOrientation = .left
            print("Device: LandscapeLeft")
        }else if (deviceOrientation == .landscapeRight){
            imageOrientation = .right
            print("Device LandscapeRight")
        }else if (deviceOrientation == .portraitUpsideDown){
            imageOrientation = .down
            print("Device PortraitUpsideDown")
        }else{
            print("Unknown Device Orientation")
        }
        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {(imageDataSampleBuffer, error) in
            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
            let dataProvider  = CGDataProvider(data: imageData! as CFData)
            let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent )
            self.imageProcessed = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: imageOrientation!)
            //print("Image Orientation: \(self.imageProcessed?.imageOrientation.rawValue)")
            print("ImageO: \(imageOrientation!.rawValue)")

            self.cameraView.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: self.imageProcessed!)

            self.captureSession.stopRunning()
        })
    }
}


@IBAction func focusAndExposeTap(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let devicePoint = self.previewLayer?.captureDevicePointOfInterest(for: gestureRecognizer.location(in: gestureRecognizer.view))
    focus(with: .autoFocus, exposureMode: .autoExpose, at: devicePoint!, monitorSubjectAreaChange: true)
}

private func focus(with focusMode: AVCaptureFocusMode, exposureMode: AVCaptureExposureMode, at devicePoint: CGPoint, monitorSubjectAreaChange: Bool)
{
    if let device = captureDevice
    {
        do{
            try device.lockForConfiguration()
            if device.isFocusPointOfInterestSupported && device.isFocusModeSupported(focusMode)
            {
                device.focusPointOfInterest = devicePoint
                device.focusMode = focusMode
            }
            if device.isExposurePointOfInterestSupported && device.isExposureModeSupported(exposureMode)
            {
                device.exposurePointOfInterest = devicePoint
                device.exposureMode = exposureMode
            }
            device.isSubjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled = monitorSubjectAreaChange
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        }catch{
            print("Could not lock device for configuration: \(error)")
        }
    }
}


@IBAction func showCirclesInPic(_ sender: Any) {
    if imageProcessed != nil {
        previewLayer!.removeFromSuperlayer()
        cameraView.addSubview(imageProcessedView)

        if (imageProcessed!.imageOrientation != .up){
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageProcessed!.size, false, imageProcessed!.scale)
            imageProcessed!.draw(in: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: imageProcessed!.size.width, height: imageProcessed!.size.height))
            imageProcessed = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        }
        imageProcessedView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageProcessedView.image = imageProcessed
        //print("ImageProcessed: \(ImageProcessingCV.showCircles(imageProcessed)!)")
    }
}


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the orientation of the camera output while taking picture you should add a listener on the orientation changes using NotificationCenter. I will be attaching a sample code for a camera using AVFoundation that you may use.
Please note that the capture and flip camera are added programmatically. Even more, you can set an image for the flip cam(there is a comment to tell you where to set it).
**Code Fixed**

```
//
//  CameraViewController.swift
//  MatchFriend
//
//  Created by Tarek Ezzat Abdallah on 10/1/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Tarek. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class CameraViewController: UIViewController{

    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
    var imageToSend: UIImage!
    // If we find a device we'll store it here for later use
    var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?

    @IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!
    var captureButton: UIButton!
    var flipCam:UIButton!
    var camPos:String = "back"
    func capture(_ sender: AnyObject)
    {
        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput?.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        {
            stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection)
            {
                (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
                let dataProvider  = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as! CFData)
                let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent )
                let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)


            }
        }


    }
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cameraView.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.view.backgroundColor = .clear

        captureButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 160, y: 580, width: 80, height: 80))
        captureButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CameraViewController.capture(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        flipCam = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40))
        flipCam.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CameraViewController.flip), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(captureButton)
        self.view.addSubview(flipCam)
        captureButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(CameraViewController.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)



        //        let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        camStart(camPos)
        setViews()

    }
    func camStart(_ position: String)
    {
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

        let videoDevices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        var capDevice:AVCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

        if(position == "back")
        {
            for device in videoDevices!
            {
                let device = device as! AVCaptureDevice
                if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.back
                {
                    capDevice = device
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        else{

            for device in videoDevices!
            {
                let device = device as! AVCaptureDevice
                if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front
                {
                    capDevice = device
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        //        var error : NSError?
        let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: capDevice)

        if (captureSession?.canAddInput(input) != nil){

            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
            stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

            if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) != nil){
                captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
                previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                previewLayer!.frame = self.view.layer.frame
                previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)


                captureSession?.startRunning()
            }
        }

    }
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        captureButton.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/2 - 40, y: self.view.frame.height - 70 - 40, width: 80, height: 80)
        flipCam.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/6 - 40, y: self.view.frame.height - 60 - 40, width: 80, height: 80)
        //add the image to flip camera
        //flipCam.setImage(UIImage(named: "switchCam"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        flipCam.setTitle("flip", for: .normal)

        if previewLayer != nil{
            previewLayer!.frame = self.view.frame
        }

    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        setViews()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func setViews()
    {
        captureButton.layer.cornerRadius = captureButton.layer.bounds.width/2
        captureButton.layer.borderWidth = 1

    }

    func configureDevice()
    {
        let error: NSErrorPointer? = nil
        if let device = captureDevice {
            do {
                try captureDevice!.lockForConfiguration()

            } catch let error1 as NSError
            {
                error??.pointee = error1
            }

            device.focusMode = .locked
            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        }

    }
    func flip()
    {
        captureSession?.stopRunning()
        if camPos == "back"
        {
            camPos = "front"
        }
        else{
            camPos = "back"

        }
        camStart(camPos)

    }
    func rotated() {
        if UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.current.orientation) {
            if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft{
                previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeRight
            }
            else
            {
                previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeLeft

            }
        }

        if UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.current.orientation) {
            if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portrait{

                previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
            }
            else
            {
                previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portraitUpsideDown

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just tried to copy this code in a new project, but it says "Use of undeclared type 'TOCropViewControllerDelegate'" and some other error messages concerning "TOCrop..." Do I have to import something else than AVFoundation and UIKit to make it work?

Comment: I'll fix it in a minute and upload it again

Comment: I added the listener and the rotated function to my project. But it only turns the previewLayer and it does not set the orientation to the metadata of the picture I capture. When I set the captured picture to an uiimageview it is always rotated wrong. I do not want to change the orientation of the previewView, but I want to save the orientation to the metadata of the captured picture to display it in an imageView.

Comment: I just saw that also my DeviceOrientation does not change. It is always portrait. I don't know why...

Comment: I am sorry I am not being able to help more than that since this code was working perfectly with me! hope you find a solution ...